# iOS : Display hidden list upon row selection

Tags: ios, ios7

In UITableViewCell, I want to have an option such that upon 'tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath', it opens up and displays some hidden list. And when we press it again, this list contracts back.

Can you please guide me in this direction?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

I'm sure this can be used in a tablewviewcell as well.